# After deploying [react-router] "did not match any routes"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I´m currently developing a React-Redux Appliaction using Webpack & npm.

While development I run `"start": "node server.js"` (from my package.json) and my app is then reachable on `localhost:3000/myApp`.

But I would like to make this App available to other users. I have a linux server running apache, where some of my previously jQuery Apps are running that work fine.

However, to bundle my React App I run `"production": "webpack -p"` and the output of this is `/dist/bundle.js`. Afterwards, I created a html file, included the bundle.js on put both on the server

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
 <head>
   <title>Urlaub-planer</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="./Urlaubspalner/css/daterangepicker.css" type="text/css">-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js">         </script>

   <!-- Auth0Lock script -->
    <script src="//cdn.auth0.com/js/lock-9.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
   <body>
    <div class="todoapp" id="root"></div>
      <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
     </body>
    </html>
```

When trying to access I got the following error:

`browser.js?26d3:49Warning: [react-router] Location "/test/index.html" did not match any routes`

This is the File where my Routes are defined

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import {Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory} from 'react-router'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'

 import App from './containers/App'
 import VacationSummary from './containers/vacation/VacationSummary'
 import VacationRequest from './containers/vacation/VacationRequest'
 import VacationRequestSummary from './containers/vacation/VacationRequestSummary'

 import Home from './containers/Home'
 import Demo from './components/Demo'
 import rootReducer from './reducers/reducers'
 import thunkMiddleware from 'redux-thunk'

 var injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
 injectTapEventPlugin();

 const logger = createLogger();

  let createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware, logger)  (createStore)

  let store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer)

  let rootElement = document.getElementById('root')

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
     module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
    const nextRootReducer = require('./reducers').default
    store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer)
    })
  }

  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
         <Route path="Home" component={Home}/>
         <Route path="VacationSummary" component={VacationSummary}/>
         <Route path="VacationRequest" component={VacationRequest}/>
         <Route path="VacationRequestSummary" component= {VacationRequestSummary}/>
     </Route>
  </Router>
    </Provider>,
    rootElement
  )
```

I have found several Questions on SO with a similar purpose, but they are mostly having problems, when running this with the webpack-dev-server.
I want it as I said on my traditional apache server.

What do I have to do, to make this work outside of my development Environment?
Sorry if that Q is to basic, but it is my first project using all this new npm, webpack, node ... stuff and so on.

Finally my package.json

```
   {
   "name": "Urlaubsplaner",
   "version": "0.0.1",
   "main": "index.js",
   "scripts": {
     "server": "node server/server.js",
      "start": "node server.js",
      "watch": "webpack --watch",
      "production": "webpack -p"
    },
    "author": "Auth0",
     "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
     "classnames": "^2.2.5",
     "css-loader": "^0.23.1",
      "material-ui": "^0.15.2",
     "moment": "^2.13.0",
     "react": "^15.1.0",
     "react-bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^3.1.0",
     "react-dom": "*",
     "react-redux": "*",
     "react-router": "*",
      "react-tabs": "^0.7.0",
      "react-tap-event-plugin": "^1.0.0",
      "react-yearly-calendar": "^1.1.4",
    "redux": "*",
     "redux-form": "^5.2.5",
     "redux-logger": "^2.6.1",
      "redux-thunk": "*",
     "style-loader": "^0.13.1"
    },
   "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^5.6.18",
    "babel-loader": "^5.1.4",
     "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^1.1.0",
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "webpack": "^1.9.11",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.2.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.2.0"
    }
  }
```

And my webpack.config

```
  var path = require('path')
 var webpack = require('webpack')

 module.exports = {
   devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map',
   entry: [
   'webpack-hot-middleware/client',
    './index'
   ],
   output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
     publicPath: '/static/'
   },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
   ],
   module: {
     loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
      {test: /\.js$/,
      loaders: [ 'babel' ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: __dirname
      }]
    }
  }
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

According to your current react router paths following links would work:-

- /
- /VacationSummary
- /VacationRequest
- /VacationRequestSummary

I cannot find /test/home.html route anywhere in your react-router. So it would throw error for sure. Also you dont need to specific **.html**  in the end for links.

Also I would suggest you to make your /Home Index Route instead of Route.

Now are you localhost:3000/myApp this working, because it should not as myApp is not there in your router urls.

So you home page(or index.html) should be accessible at localhost:3000 from the code you have shared above.

Comment: The pages are accessible at localhost:3000, but this is via a node server. But I want it just running via a normal apache server, which is on another domain. And everytime a push a index.html that includes the bundle.js from /dist on my server, it says not matching routes